# More erratic behavior on c++ builder xe2: DYNAMIC_CAST always returns NULL

Tags: c++, c++builder, dynamic-cast, c++builder-xe2

Well, I'm close to abandon about twelve years of delphi and c++ builder due Embarcadero. Never see so problematic IDE.

This time the problem is with dynamic_cast always returning NULL.

In the same unit I derived two classes:

```
class TStructTreeNode: public TTreeNode
class PACKAGE TStructTreeView : public TTreeView
```

The cast to TStructTreeView works fine:

```
TStructTreeView* tv = dynamic_cast<TStructTreeView*>( AOwner->Owner );
```

But the cast to TStructTreeNode ALWAYS RETUNS NULL:

```
TStructTreeNode* snode = dynamic_cast<TStructTreeNode*>(Items->Item[i]);
```

Notice that Items->Item[i] is really TStructTreeNode cause the next code works fine:

```
((TStructTreeNode*)(Items->Item[i]))->ToggleChecked();
```

The node as created as follows:

```
TStructTreeNode* snode = new TStructTreeNode(Items,UniqueID);
TTreeNode* node = Items->AddNode(snode,Relative,S,Ptr,Method);
```

In the same package I have other component with the classes TMDTreeNode and TMDTreeView derived in the very same way, in that unit all dynamic_casts works.

Any light is welcome.

PS: Virtual destructor functions already added as other post and not working.

Comment: Did you enable RTTI? dynamic_cast rely on it.

Comment: Yes, RTTI is enabled and other casts like dynamic_cast<TStructTreeView*>( AOwner->Owner ) in the very same unit work well.

Comment: Then I suspect that Item[i] is not really a TStructTreeNode object.

Comment: How is `Items` defined?

Comment: Items is TTreeNodes (TTreeView->Items) and hold the TTreeNode collection.

Comment: Item[i] is TStructTreeNode, cause I create then (new TStructTreeNode) and when I call functions that exists only in TStructTreeNode this works pretty fine ((TStructTreeNode*)(Items->Item[i]))->ToggleChecked();.

Comment: Call `Item->ClassName()` to verify that the Item is actually a `TStructTreeNode` and not a generic `TTreeNode`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to type-cast a `TTreeNode` pointer to a `TStructTreeNode` pointer with `dynamic_cast`, you have to instantiate a real `TStructTreeNode` instance to satisfy the cast.  If you are using general `TTreeNodes` methods, like `Add()`, then override the virtual `CreateNode()` method to tell the `TTreeView` to create `TStructTreeNode` instances and not `TTreeNode` instances.  For example:

```
class PACKAGE TStructTreeView : public TTreeView
{
protected:
    virtual TTreeNode* __fastcall CreateNode();
};

TTreeNode* __fastcall TStructTreeView::CreateNode()
{
    return new TStructTreeNode(Items);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm not using `TTreeNode`, I'm creating a `TStructTreeNode` and then adding it to `TreeView->Items`. Note that the cast `((TStructTreeNode*)(Items->Item[i]))->ToggleChecked();` are working with a function that don't exists on `TTreeNode`

Comment: How are you adding a `TStructTreeNode` to the `Items` collection exactly? There are cases where `TTreeView` may need to create temp nodes and assign existing nodes to them, so you need to make sure your `TTreeView` always creates `TStructTreeNode` instances so they match.

Comment: I'm using: `TStructTreeNode* snode = new TStructTreeNode(Items,UniqueID);
Items->AddNode(snode,Relative,S,Ptr,Method);`

Answer (score 0):

Adding PACKAGE to the class definition of TStructTreeNode has solved the problem

```
class PACKAGE TStructTreeNode: public TTreeNode
```

But yet seems Embarcadero works erratically, cause in same package I have another unit in which dynamic casting a class called TMDTreeNode works fine without PACKAGE instruction.

```
class TMDTreeNode: public TTreeNode
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
((TStructTreeNode*)(Items->Item[i]))->ToggleChecked();
```

does not "prove" that `Items->Item[i]` is a `(TStructTreeNode *)`, or even close. All it says is to interpret the memory at the location currently being pointed to by that pointer as if it were a `TStructTreeNode`.

If it's not a `TStructTreeNode` then the behaviour is undefined, meaning that it may or may not appear to succeed.  Even if it is a TStructTreeNode, then the `dynamic_cast<>` will fail if the data type of `Items->Item[i]` is not a pointer to a base class of `TStructTreeNode`. I hope you are not expecting that `dynamic_cast<>` will "decode" a `void *` or something.

Can you show the declaration of `Item` ?